# find determinant value using property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$ det A= \left(\begin{array}{ccc} a & b & c \\
      d & e & f \\
      g & h & i  \end{array}\right) =12$

$A= \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 3a & 3b & 3c \\
      d+2a & e+2b & f+2c \\
      -\frac{1}{2}g & -\frac{1}{2}h& -\frac{1}{2}i  \end{array}\right).$

so according to determinant property, multiply first row with 3, $-\frac{1}{2}$times row three, and add 2 times first row to second row,but it wont change the determinant. so the new determinant will be $3\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot 12$. Is my assumption true?

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Comment: You should label the new matrix by $B$ (not $A$).

Comment: @Vixf  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's a good reasoning way, it looks ok